# Can the farmer villager plant crops without composter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to trade with the farmer, locking his profession, and then remove the composter? I know it is his profession block, so I was wondering if he could still plant his crops without the composter being there. (I know this is something I could easily test myself, but I currently don't have Minecraft on my computer, and I'm planning some builds in my head)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you trade with the farmer at least once, they will remain a farmer even after you remove the composter, and cannot change or lose their profession. Farmers will not need composters to plant crops.

Comment: Look for the villager farm in https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Crop_farming